# Mapping ´ to / not working

Tags: vimrc, key-bindings

I'm trying to map ´ to / and ¨ to ? as follows:

```
nnoremap ´ /
nnoremap ¨ ?
```

It works fine if the first letter behind de map key is not any of i, I, a, A, o, O... guessing is something wrong with the getting into insert mode keys.

I haven't found the solution, maybe is a silly thing I missed
Could you help me?

Comment: Are you on a Mac?  Those are "dead keys" on a Mac that produce special characters when you type the right following character.  E.g., ´e produces é.

Comment: Welcome to [vi.se]! Please [edit] with the response to Wolf's comment

Comment: I'm voting to close the question until OP's answered Wolf's question

Comment: Wolf was right.